# Is there an efficient way of passing arguments?

Tags: python, argument-passing

Is there an alternative to writing 'codec' four times in the argument list?

```
codec = 'XVID'
fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC(codec[0], codec[1], codec[2], codec[3])
```

When I do this the argument is just one because the result of ','.join(ls) is a string. Is there a way to pass four arguments without having to do what is in the above example?

```
codec = 'XVID'
ls = list(codec)
fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC(','.join(ls))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*args` argument unpacking:

```
cv.CV_FOURCC(*codec)
```

Any iterable passed using a `*` prefix is unpacked into separate arguments; a string is an iterable too and results in `len(string)` arguments, each a single character:

```
>>> codec = 'XVID'
>>> def demo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
...     print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4
... 
>>> demo(*codec)
X V I D
```

You can use `**` to treat an argument as a mapping of keyword parameters (each key-value pair becoming an argument), and the same syntax in a *function signature* lets you *capture* variable arguments as a tuple or mapping, respectively. See [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)